# Estimating class probabilities given discriminative functions per class

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification

What is the effective way to estimating class probabilities per class, if I know discriminative functions for each class (I have trained ML models giving some scores). My naive implementation is to use softmax function using model scores, but is there any better way?

Comment: Have you considered naive bayes ?

Comment: Top of these classifiers or as alone ?

Comment: Naive Bayes can easily be configured to give class probabilities from the raw data, I don't know if those probabilities will fulfil whatever criteria you are building a system to satisfy, but it shouldn't take very long to try it and see how they fit your needs.

Comment: Let us know how it goes.